# Query String is replacing my variable equals sign with a % causing html encoding of value

Tags: php, wordpress, string

I am having a problem with my query string format.  I have tried every way to get the value to work, but every time for the deposit value, it changes the = to a % and uses the numbers within the value of that parameter as an html entity.

I have tried converting to a string, removing the encoding from the email headers and nothing is working to avoid it.  I just need to pass the deposit value and the email value.  The email value is passing with no problem at all.  I have changed the order of the variables but again this has not worked.

I have spent hours trying to get this to work but am now at the end of my tether as nothing I try works.  Cannot find any sort of answer either so would really appreciate someone pushing me in the right direction.

Please see the code below:

```
$querystring = print_r('deposit=', true);
$querystring .= sprintf("%5.2f", $deposit);
$querystring .= '&email=';
$querystring .= $email;
$url = 'http://localhost/escalada/deposit/?' . $querystring;

$to = $email;
$subject = 'Your Package with Escalada';

$headers = array('Content-Type: text/html;');

$body = ' <div class="es-wrapper-color" style="background-color:#F6F6F6;"> <!--[if gte mso 9]><v:background xmlns:v="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:vml" fill="t"> <v:fill type="tile" color="#f6f6f6"></v:fill> </v:background><![endif]--> <table class="es-wrapper" width="100%" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" style="mso-table-lspace:0pt;mso-table-rspace:0pt;border-collapse:collapse;border-spacing:0px;padding:0;Margin:0;width:100%;height:100%;background-repeat:repeat;background-position:center top;"> <tr style="border-collapse:collapse;"> <td valign="top" style="padding:0;Margin:0;"> <table class="es-content" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" align="center" style="mso-table-lspace:0pt;mso-table-rspace:0pt;border-collapse:collapse;border-spacing:0px;table-layout:fixed !important;width:100%;"> <tr style="border-collapse:collapse;"> <td class="es-adaptive" align="center" style="padding:0;Margin:0;"> <table';
$body .= ' class="es-content-body" width="600" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" align="center" style="mso-table-lspace:0pt;mso-table-rspace:0pt;border-collapse:collapse;border-spacing:0px;background-color:#FFFFFF;"> <tr style="border-collapse:collapse;"> <td align="left" style="Margin:0;padding-top:10px;padding-bottom:10px;padding-left:20px;padding-right:20px;"> <!--[if mso]><table width="560"><tr><td width="268" valign="top"><![endif]--> <table class="es-left" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" align="left" style="mso-table-lspace:0pt;mso-table-rspace:0pt;border-collapse:collapse;border-spacing:0px;float:left;"> <tr style="border-collapse:collapse;"> <td width="268" align="left" style="padding:0;Margin:0;"> <table width="100%" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" style="mso-table-lspace:0pt;mso-table-rspace:0pt;border-collapse:collapse;border-spacing:0px;"> <tr style="border-collapse:collapse;"> <td class="es-infoblock es-m-txt-c" align="left"';
$body .= ' style="padding:0;Margin:0;line-height:14px;font-size:12px;color:#CCCCCC;"> <p style="Margin:0;-webkit-text-size-adjust:none;-ms-text-size-adjust:none;mso-line-height-rule:exactly;font-size:12px;font-family:arial, "helvetica neue", helvetica, sans-serif;line-height:14px;color:#CCCCCC;">Your Package Quote from Escalada</p> </td> </tr> </table> </td> </tr> </table> <!--[if mso]></td><td width="20"></td><td width="272" valign="top"><![endif]--> <table class="es-right" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" align="right" style="mso-table-lspace:0pt;mso-table-rspace:0pt;border-collapse:collapse;border-spacing:0px;float:right;"> <tr style="border-collapse:collapse;"> <td width="272" align="left" style="padding:0;Margin:0;"> <table width="100%" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" style="mso-table-lspace:0pt;mso-table-rspace:0pt;border-collapse:collapse;border-spacing:0px;"> <tr style="border-collapse:collapse;"> <td class="es-infoblock es-m-txt-c" align="right"';
$body .= ' style="padding:0;Margin:0;line-height:14px;font-size:12px;color:#CCCCCC;"> <p style="Margin:0;-webkit-text-size-adjust:none;-ms-text-size-adjust:none;mso-line-height-rule:exactly;font-size:12px;font-family:arial, "helvetica neue", helvetica, sans-serif;line-height:14px;color:#CCCCCC;"></p> </td> </tr> </table> </td> </tr> </table> <!--[if mso]></td></tr></table><![endif]--> </td> </tr> </table> </td> </tr> </table> <table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" class="es-content" align="center" style="mso-table-lspace:0pt;mso-table-rspace:0pt;border-collapse:collapse;border-spacing:0px;table-layout:fixed !important;width:100%;"> <tr style="border-collapse:collapse;"> <td align="center"';
$body .= ' style="padding:0;Margin:0;"> <table bgcolor="#ffffff" class="es-content-body" align="center" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" width="600" style="mso-table-lspace:0pt;mso-table-rspace:0pt;border-collapse:collapse;border-spacing:0px;background-color:#FFFFFF;"> <tr style="border-collapse:collapse;"> <td align="left" style="padding:0;Margin:0;padding-top:20px;padding-left:20px;padding-right:20px;"> <table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" width="100%" style="mso-table-lspace:0pt;mso-table-rspace:0pt;border-collapse:collapse;border-spacing:0px;"> <tr style="border-collapse:collapse;"> <td width="560" align="center" valign="top" style="padding:0;Margin:0;"> <table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" width="100%" style="mso-table-lspace:0pt;mso-table-rspace:0pt;border-collapse:collapse;border-spacing:0px;"> <tr style="border-collapse:collapse;"> <td align="center" style="padding:0;Margin:0;"> <img class="adapt-img"';
$body .= ' src="https://rhfvb.stripocdn.email/content/guids/CABINET_a75acf8bafcdc3cdc2c12723b81de2f0/images/72941552065601131.png" alt="" style="display:block;border:0;outline:none;text-decoration:none;-ms-interpolation-mode:bicubic;" width="560" height="155.47"></td> </tr> </table> </td> </tr> </table> </td> </tr> </table> </td> </tr> </table> <table class="es-content" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" align="center" style="mso-table-lspace:0pt;mso-table-rspace:0pt;border-collapse:collapse;border-spacing:0px;table-layout:fixed !important;width:100%;"> <tr style="border-collapse:collapse;"> <td align="center" style="padding:0;Margin:0;"> <table class="es-content-body" width="600" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" bgcolor="#ffffff" align="center" style="mso-table-lspace:0pt;mso-table-rspace:0pt;border-collapse:collapse;border-spacing:0px;background-color:#FFFFFF;"> <tr style="border-collapse:collapse;"> <td align="left"';
$body .= ' style="padding:0;Margin:0;padding-left:20px;padding-right:20px;padding-top:30px;"> <table width="100%" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" style="mso-table-lspace:0pt;mso-table-rspace:0pt;border-collapse:collapse;border-spacing:0px;"> <tr style="border-collapse:collapse;"> <td width="560" valign="top" align="center" style="padding:0;Margin:0;"> <table width="100%" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" style="mso-table-lspace:0pt;mso-table-rspace:0pt;border-collapse:collapse;border-spacing:0px;"> <tr style="border-collapse:collapse;"> <td align="left" style="padding:0;Margin:0;padding-bottom:5px;"> <h1 style="Margin:0;line-height:36px;mso-line-height-rule:exactly;font-family:arial, "helvetica neue", helvetica, sans-serif;font-size:30px;font-style:normal;font-weight:normal;color:#333333;">Your Package from Escalada</h1> </td> </tr> <tr style="border-collapse:collapse;"> <td class="es-m-txt-c" align="left" style="padding:0;Margin:0;padding-bottom:10px;"> <p';
$body .= ' style="Margin:0;-webkit-text-size-adjust:none;-ms-text-size-adjust:none;mso-line-height-rule:exactly;font-size:14px;font-family:arial, "helvetica neue", helvetica, sans-serif;line-height:21px;color:#333333;">Hi,&nbsp;</p><p style="Margin:0;-webkit-text-size-adjust:none;-ms-text-size-adjust:none;mso-line-height-rule:exactly;font-size:14px;font-family:arial, "helvetica neue", helvetica, sans-serif;line-height:21px;color:#333333;"><br></p><p style="Margin:0;-webkit-text-size-adjust:none;-ms-text-size-adjust:none;mso-line-height-rule:exactly;font-size:14px;font-family:arial, "helvetica neue", helvetica, sans-serif;line-height:21px;color:#333333;">Thanks for choosing Escalada!&nbsp; Please see your package quote below.&nbsp; If you wish to book, please click the button below, reply to this email or give us a call.</p> </td> </tr> <tr style="border-collapse:collapse;"> <td class="es-m-txt-c" align="left" style="padding:0;Margin:0;"> <h3';
$body .= ' style="Margin:0;line-height:24px;mso-line-height-rule:exactly;font-family:arial, "helvetica neue", helvetica, sans-serif;font-size:20px;font-style:normal;font-weight:normal;color:#333333;">Your Package</h3><h4 style="Margin:0;line-height:120%;mso-line-height-rule:exactly;font-family:arial, "helvetica neue", helvetica, sans-serif;color:#333333;"><br></h4><h4 style="Margin:0;line-height:120%;mso-line-height-rule:exactly;font-family:arial, "helvetica neue", helvetica, sans-serif;">Your Dates are from ' . $arrival . ' to ' . $departure . '</h4><h4 style="Margin:0;line-height:120%;mso-line-height-rule:exactly;font-family:arial, "helvetica neue", helvetica, sans-serif;color:#333333;"><br></h4><h4 style="Margin:0;line-height:120%;mso-line-height-rule:exactly;font-family:arial, "helvetica neue", helvetica, sans-serif;color:#333333;">Total Price £' . "$total" . '</h4><p';
$body .= ' style="Margin:0;-webkit-text-size-adjust:none;-ms-text-size-adjust:none;mso-line-height-rule:exactly;font-size:14px;font-family:arial, "helvetica neue", helvetica, sans-serif;line-height:21px;color:#333333;"><br><h4 style="Margin:0;line-height:120%;mso-line-height-rule:exactly;font-family:arial, "helvetica neue", helvetica, sans-serif;color:#333333;">Deposit Amount £' . $deposit . '</h4><p</p><h4 style="Margin:0;line-height:120%;mso-line-height-rule:exactly;font-family:arial, "helvetica neue", helvetica, sans-serif;color:#333333;">Your package includes:</h4><h4 style="Margin:0;line-height:120%;mso-line-height-rule:exactly;font-family:arial, "helvetica neue", helvetica, sans-serif;"></h4><p style="Margin:0;-webkit-text-size-adjust:none;-ms-text-size-adjust:none;mso-line-height-rule:exactly;font-size:14px;font-family:arial, "helvetica neue", helvetica, sans-serif;line-height:21px;color:#333333;">' . print_r($accomm, true) . '</p><p style="Margin:0;-webkit-text-size-adjust:none;-ms-text-size-adjust:none;mso-line-height-rule:exactly;font-size:14px;font-family:arial, "helvetica neue", helvetica, sans-serif;line-height:21px;color:#333333;">' . implode(", ",$bikes) . '</p><p';
$body .= ' style="Margin:0;-webkit-text-size-adjust:none;-ms-text-size-adjust:none;mso-line-height-rule:exactly;font-size:14px;font-family:arial, "helvetica neue", helvetica, sans-serif;line-height:21px;color:#333333;">' . implode(", ",$extras) . '</p><p style="Margin:0;-webkit-text-size-adjust:none;-ms-text-size-adjust:none;mso-line-height-rule:exactly;font-size:14px;font-family:arial, "helvetica neue", helvetica, sans-serif;line-height:21px;color:#333333;"><br></p> </td> </tr> <tr style="border-collapse:collapse;"> <td align="center" style="padding:0;Margin:0;"> <span class="es-button-border" style="border-style:solid;border-color:#741B47;background:#741B47;border-width:3px;display:block;border-radius:5px;width:auto;"> <a href="' . $url . '" class="es-button" target="_blank" style="color:white; mso-style-priority:100 !important;text-decoration:none;-webkit-text-size-adjust:none;-ms-text-size-adjust:none;mso-line-height-rule:exactly;font-family:arial, "helvetica neue", helvetica,';
$body .= ' sans-serif;font-size:16px;color:#FFFFFF;border-style:solid;border-color:#741B47;border-width:20px 0px;display:block;background:#741B47;border-radius:5px;font-weight:normal;font-style:normal;line-height:19px;width:auto;text-align:center;">Confirm Booking Now</a> </span> </td> </tr> <tr style="border-collapse:collapse;"> <td class="es-m-txt-c" align="left" style="padding:0;Margin:0;"> <p style="Margin:0;-webkit-text-size-adjust:none;-ms-text-size-adjust:none;mso-line-height-rule:exactly;font-size:14px;font-family:arial, "helvetica neue", helvetica, sans-serif;line-height:21px;color:#333333;"><br></p><p style="Margin:0;-webkit-text-size-adjust:none;-ms-text-size-adjust:none;mso-line-height-rule:exactly;font-size:14px;font-family:arial, "helvetica neue", helvetica, sans-serif;line-height:21px;color:#333333;">If there is anything else you require, please do not hesitate to contact us! <br></p><p';
$body .= ' style="Margin:0;-webkit-text-size-adjust:none;-ms-text-size-adjust:none;mso-line-height-rule:exactly;font-size:14px;font-family:arial, "helvetica neue", helvetica, sans-serif;line-height:21px;color:#333333;"><br></p><p style="Margin:0;-webkit-text-size-adjust:none;-ms-text-size-adjust:none;mso-line-height-rule:exactly;font-size:14px;font-family:arial, "helvetica neue", helvetica, sans-serif;line-height:21px;color:#333333;">See you soon,</p> </td> </tr> </table> </td> </tr> </table> </td> </tr> </table> </td> </tr> </table> <table class="es-content" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" align="center" style="mso-table-lspace:0pt;mso-table-rspace:0pt;border-collapse:collapse;border-spacing:0px;table-layout:fixed !important;width:100%;"> <tr style="border-collapse:collapse;"> <td align="center" style="padding:0;Margin:0;"> <table class="es-content-body" style="mso-table-lspace:0pt;mso-table-rspace:0pt;border-collapse:collapse;border-spacing:0px;background-color:#FFFFFF;" width="600"';
$body .= ' cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" bgcolor="#ffffff" align="center"> <tr style="border-collapse:collapse;"> <td align="left" style="padding:0;Margin:0;"> <table width="100%" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" style="mso-table-lspace:0pt;mso-table-rspace:0pt;border-collapse:collapse;border-spacing:0px;"> <tr style="border-collapse:collapse;"> <td width="600" valign="top" align="center" style="padding:0;Margin:0;"> <table width="100%" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" style="mso-table-lspace:0pt;mso-table-rspace:0pt;border-collapse:collapse;border-spacing:0px;"> <tr style="border-collapse:collapse;"> <td class="es-m-txt-c" align="left" style="padding:0;Margin:0;"> <p style="Margin:0;-webkit-text-size-adjust:none;-ms-text-size-adjust:none;mso-line-height-rule:exactly;font-size:14px;font-family:arial, "helvetica neue", helvetica, sans-serif;line-height:21px;color:#333333;"><br></p> </td> </tr> </table> </td> </tr> </table> </td> </tr> <tr style="border-collapse:collapse;"> <td align="left"';
$body .= ' style="Margin:0;padding-top:20px;padding-bottom:20px;padding-left:20px;padding-right:20px;"> <!--[if mso]><table width="560" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0"><tr><td width="270" valign="top"><![endif]--> <table class="es-left" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" align="left" style="mso-table-lspace:0pt;mso-table-rspace:0pt;border-collapse:collapse;border-spacing:0px;float:left;"> <tr style="border-collapse:collapse;"> <td class="es-m-p20b" width="270" align="left" style="padding:0;Margin:0;"> <table width="100%" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" style="mso-table-lspace:0pt;mso-table-rspace:0pt;border-collapse:collapse;border-spacing:0px;"> <tr style="border-collapse:collapse;"> <td align="center" style="padding:0;Margin:0;"> <img class="adapt-img" src="https://rhfvb.stripocdn.email/content/guids/CABINET_a75acf8bafcdc3cdc2c12723b81de2f0/images/98791552066180911.png" alt="" style="display:block;border:0;outline:none;text-decoration:none;-ms-interpolation-mode:bicubic;"';
$body .= ' width="270" height="167.40"></td> </tr> </table> </td> </tr> </table> <!--[if mso]></td><td width="20"></td><td width="270" valign="top"><![endif]--> <table class="es-right" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" align="right" style="mso-table-lspace:0pt;mso-table-rspace:0pt;border-collapse:collapse;border-spacing:0px;float:right;"> <tr style="border-collapse:collapse;"> <td width="270" align="left" style="padding:0;Margin:0;"> <table width="100%" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" style="mso-table-lspace:0pt;mso-table-rspace:0pt;border-collapse:collapse;border-spacing:0px;"> <tr style="border-collapse:collapse;"> <td class="es-m-txt-c" align="right" style="padding:0;Margin:0;padding-top:5px;"> <table class="es-table-not-adapt es-social" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" style="mso-table-lspace:0pt;mso-table-rspace:0pt;border-collapse:collapse;border-spacing:0px;"> <tr style="border-collapse:collapse;"> <td valign="top" align="center" style="padding:0;Margin:0;padding-right:10px;"> <a';
$body .= ' target="_blank" href="https://www.facebook.com/escaladacycling/" style="-webkit-text-size-adjust:none;-ms-text-size-adjust:none;mso-line-height-rule:exactly;font-family:arial, "helvetica neue", helvetica, sans-serif;font-size:14px;text-decoration:underline;color:#333333;"><img title="Facebook" src="https://rhfvb.stripocdn.email/content/assets/img/social-icons/logo-black/facebook-logo-black.png" alt="Fb" width="32" height="32" style="display:block;border:0;outline:none;text-decoration:none;-ms-interpolation-mode:bicubic;"></a> </td> <td valign="top" align="center" style="padding:0;Margin:0;"> <a target="_blank" href="https://www.instagram.com/escalada_cycling/" style="-webkit-text-size-adjust:none;-ms-text-size-adjust:none;mso-line-height-rule:exactly;font-family:arial, "helvetica neue", helvetica, sans-serif;font-size:14px;text-decoration:underline;color:#333333;"><img title="Instagram"';
$body .= ' src="https://rhfvb.stripocdn.email/content/assets/img/social-icons/logo-black/instagram-logo-black.png" alt="Inst" width="32" height="32" style="display:block;border:0;outline:none;text-decoration:none;-ms-interpolation-mode:bicubic;"></a> </td> </tr> </table> </td> </tr> </table> </td> </tr> </table> <!--[if mso]></td></tr></table><![endif]--> </td> </tr> </table> </td> </tr> </table> <table class="es-footer" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" align="center" style="mso-table-lspace:0pt;mso-table-rspace:0pt;border-collapse:collapse;border-spacing:0px;table-layout:fixed !important;width:100%;background-color:transparent;background-repeat:repeat;background-position:center top;"> <tr style="border-collapse:collapse;"> <td align="center" style="padding:0;Margin:0;"> <table class="es-footer-body" width="600" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" align="center" style="mso-table-lspace:0pt;mso-table-rspace:0pt;border-collapse:collapse;border-spacing:0px;background-color:#808080;"> <tr';
$body .= ' style="border-collapse:collapse;"> <td align="left" style="Margin:0;padding-top:20px;padding-bottom:20px;padding-left:20px;padding-right:20px;"> <table width="100%" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" style="mso-table-lspace:0pt;mso-table-rspace:0pt;border-collapse:collapse;border-spacing:0px;"> <tr style="border-collapse:collapse;"> <td width="560" valign="top" align="center" style="padding:0;Margin:0;"> <table width="100%" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" style="mso-table-lspace:0pt;mso-table-rspace:0pt;border-collapse:collapse;border-spacing:0px;"> <tr style="border-collapse:collapse;"> <td align="center" style="padding:0;Margin:0;"> <p style="Margin:0;-webkit-text-size-adjust:none;-ms-text-size-adjust:none;mso-line-height-rule:exactly;font-size:14px;font-family:arial, "helvetica neue", helvetica, sans-serif;line-height:21px;color:#FFFFFF;">Calle Alcant 32<br></p><p';
$body .= ' style="Margin:0;-webkit-text-size-adjust:none;-ms-text-size-adjust:none;mso-line-height-rule:exactly;font-size:14px;font-family:arial, "helvetica neue", helvetica, sans-serif;line-height:21px;color:#FFFFFF;">03727</p><p style="Margin:0;-webkit-text-size-adjust:none;-ms-text-size-adjust:none;mso-line-height-rule:exactly;font-size:14px;font-family:arial, "helvetica neue", helvetica, sans-serif;line-height:21px;color:#FFFFFF;">Xalo</p><p style="Margin:0;-webkit-text-size-adjust:none;-ms-text-size-adjust:none;mso-line-height-rule:exactly;font-size:14px;font-family:arial, "helvetica neue", helvetica, sans-serif;line-height:21px;color:#FFFFFF;">Spain</p> </td> </tr> </table> </td> </tr> </table> </td> </tr> </table> </td> </tr> </table> <table class="es-content" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" align="center" style="mso-table-lspace:0pt;mso-table-rspace:0pt;border-collapse:collapse;border-spacing:0px;table-layout:fixed !important;width:100%;"> <tr';
$body .= ' style="border-collapse:collapse;"> <td align="center" style="padding:0;Margin:0;"> <table class="es-content-body" style="mso-table-lspace:0pt;mso-table-rspace:0pt;border-collapse:collapse;border-spacing:0px;background-color:transparent;" width="600" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" align="center"> <tr style="border-collapse:collapse;"> <td align="left" style="Margin:0;padding-left:20px;padding-right:20px;padding-top:30px;padding-bottom:30px;"> <table width="100%" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" style="mso-table-lspace:0pt;mso-table-rspace:0pt;border-collapse:collapse;border-spacing:0px;"> <tr style="border-collapse:collapse;"> <td width="560" valign="top" align="center" style="padding:0;Margin:0;"> <table width="100%" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" style="mso-table-lspace:0pt;mso-table-rspace:0pt;border-collapse:collapse;border-spacing:0px;"> <tr style="border-collapse:collapse;"> <td class="es-infoblock" align="center"';
$body .= ' style="padding:0;Margin:0;line-height:14px;font-size:12px;color:#CCCCCC;"> <a target="_blank" href="http://viewstripo.email/?utm_source=templates&utm_medium=email&utm_campaign=mockup&utm_content=trigger_newsletter" style="-webkit-text-size-adjust:none;-ms-text-size-adjust:none;mso-line-height-rule:exactly;font-family:arial, "helvetica neue", helvetica, sans-serif;font-size:12px;text-decoration:underline;color:#CCCCCC;"> <img src="https://rhfvb.stripocdn.email/content/guids/CABINET_a75acf8bafcdc3cdc2c12723b81de2f0/images/72941552065601131.png" alt="" width="125" style="display:block;border:0;outline:none;text-decoration:none;-ms-interpolation-mode:bicubic;" height="34.70"> </a> </td> </tr> </table> </td> </tr> </table> </td> </tr> </table> </td> </tr> </table> </td> </tr> </table> </div>';

wp_mail( $to, $subject, $body, $headers );

}
```

Comment: Did you look to see if there was a better way to construct your html string before doing all of this string concatenation?

Comment: Although you should rather not assemble query strings manually (`http_build_query` exists), your code seems to produce something of the form `?deposit=47.58&email=foo@bar.com`, which looks ok. So this is likely rather a problem with sending of the mail. https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/211244/few-chars-getting-replaced-with-in-mail-content-in-wp-mail seems to be a similar issue.

Comment: Lines over 76 characters in length in the message can be problematic, see https://secure.php.net/manual/de/function.mail.php#29038 I am not sure if wp_mail sends as `quoted-printable`, but if it does, try and wrap the long lines inside your message accordingly first. https://secure.php.net/manual/en/function.quoted-printable-encode.php

Comment: I've replaced the manual build of the querystring with http_build_query which builds the query, thank you for the nudge, but unfortunately I have changed the lines in class-phpmailer.php as indicated but it is still changing the querystring.  It is looking like it may either be a problem with sending mail via smtp (I am using localhost and am unable to send mail with just php) or that the lines are over 76 characters long.

Comment: Ok, having just checked, it looks like it is definitely the line length.  I have added the $url link to the subject and it is displaying correctly.  Adding the $url to the body shows the error.  Any suggestions?

Comment: Ok, it was something to do with an smtp server problem.  I have now tested using localhost and the querystring is now properly formulated.  Thank you 04FS.